# Rails 4: ActiveAdmin clears out an array field upon update

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, activeadmin

I have an ActiveAdmin model registered as such:

```
ActiveAdmin.register MyModel do
  permit_params :name, :synonyms

  filter :name

  index do
    selectable_column
    column :name

    actions
  end
end
```

I noticed that when I update an object from the ActiveAdmin interface, the synonyms are getting cleared out. Synonyms are an array field defined as such in the PostgreSQL database:

```
synonyms text[] DEFAULT '{}'::text[]
```

I tried putting the following in `app/admin/my_model.rb`:

```
controller do
  def update
    permitted_params[:my_model][:synonyms] = JSON.parse permitted_params[:my_model][:synonyms]
    super
  end
end
```

and I also tried it with `params` instead of `permitted_params` but that doesn't work either. Not sure why ActiveAdmin would be discarding this field. Am I doing something incorrectly? The project I'm working with uses ActiveAdmin 1.0.0.pre4 (I realize this is a dated version).

Any advice would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Notes: Seems this might be [a common issue](https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/issues/2064)?

Comment: try self.params['synonyms'] = JSON.parse params['my_model]['synonyms]

Comment: I see no form defined in your code. How are you exactly updating the object?  

In the app I'm helping to develop, there are even froms working without permit_params at all, using as: :select form input with multi-select for the array:  

`
form do |f|
  f.inputs do
    f.input :items, as: :select, 
                          collection: MyModel::ITEMS.values,
                          multiple: true
  end
end
`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is applicable to string arrays and I don't know about that specific version of Activeadmin, but I encountered this issue in a slightly different context.

I had a model where the array data types were decimals & integers. I had to explicitly state the type of form input to be used when editing / updating the record or nothing was passed back from the field with the update parameters. Activeadmin chose a number input by default, but it needed to be processed as a string.

```
form do |f|
  f.inputs do
    f.input :ages, as :string, :input_html => {:maxlength => '100'}
  end
end
```

I had to set maxlength manually because for some reason it was automatically being set very short. In the model, the string then has to be converted into an actual array before being saved.

```
def ages= items
  if items.is_a? String
    items = items.split(' ')
    items.each do |i|
      i.to_i
    end
  end
  super items
end
```